# How can I get an animated Dropdown-Menu?

Tags: javascript, css

I wanna have an animated Dropdown-menu as a Navigation!
   In Css I've set transition height to 1s and in Javascript I add a value
   of for the height property in an Eventlistener. When the ham-symbol is
   clicked the menu should go down in a transition of 1s. The problem is        that when I click the ham-symbol it does't move with transition...it just appears... I recently found out when I add display: block in the css dropdown menu it works, but then obviously the toggle click ham-symbol doesnt work anymore! Please help!

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">
         <img id="ham" alt="toggle menu" src="Images/hamburger.svg">
    </a>
    <div id="dropdown" class="hide-mobile">
         <ul>
             <li>
                <a href="#home_anchor">Home</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#service_anchor">Service</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#einbruch_anchor">Einbruchschutz</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</nav>


#dropdown {
        /* display: block */
        border-top: 3px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        width: 80%;
        top: 100%;
        left: 10%;
        height: 0;
        background: #fff;
        padding-top: 2.2rem;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px lightgrey;
        z-index: 1;
        transition: height 1s;
        }


let menu = document.getElementById('ham');
let nav = document.getElementById('dropdown');

menu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
nav.classList.toggle('hide-mobile');
nav.style.height = "400px";
})
```

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I tried your example in jsfiddle and it seems to be working fine for me in chrome. try this: https://jsfiddle.net/npLkc8w6/

Comment: chrome and firefox.. both are not working

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgLbdy).
You can make it better but your basic requirement is met.
You just needed to:

- toggle the `height`, not the `top`.
- set `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: thank you...yes height is better... i already found out...and i tried it in codepen and yes it works... but not in my project... there must be some other bug

Comment: Hi I just updated the question! Please have a look! Thank you!

Comment: @FlorianStöger add to your css: `overflow-y: hidden` (to hide the content when it's overflowing the container) and change `top: 100%` to `top: 0`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your solution you can try something like that :

```js
let menu = document.getElementById('ham');
let nav = document.getElementById('dropdown');

var isOpen = false;

menu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 
  if (isOpen == false){
 nav.classList.toggle('hide-mobile');
 nav.style.top = "-100%";
  isOpen = true;
  }
  else{
  nav.classList.toggle('hide-mobile');
 nav.style.top = "0%";
  isOpen = false;
  }
})
```

```css
#dropdown {
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 2.2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px lightgrey;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
 }
 
 
 /* Just for the example */
 img{
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   margin-left:-5px;
   margin-top:-5px;
 }
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#">
         <img id="ham" alt="toggle menu" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/195031-200.png">
    </a>
    <div id="dropdown" class="hide-mobile">
         <ul>
             <li>
                <a href="#home_anchor">Home</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#service_anchor">Service</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#einbruch_anchor">Einbruchschutz</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Click on "Run code snippet" to see the animation. If that does not work there is definitely a problem with your browser display, try on another machine and check that javascript is not disabled.

JSFiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/t3wrhjpq/2/

Comment: What do you mean by "transition"? The menu is hidden and appears with an animation (a "arrived from above" effect). Check the JSFiddle.

Comment: Hi! I just updated the question! Please have a look! Thank you!

Comment: I edited my answer, you can have a look. The animation work fine on my side, the way you described it.

Comment: Thank you!  Meanwhile I found a solution!